# What is the best language to code something like a macro which connect to a website and do some operations?

Tags: java

i would like to know what is the best way to code something like macro which will connect to a website and do some operation like typing the username, password and then click something in the webpage.

through java or other language.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Java can be used for that. You can also use c# or vb.net or php. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

If this is for testing, Selenium or Watir would work, if you are just trying to screen scrape any scripting language especially Python/Perl would work.

Actually the answer would vary from person to person and greatly depends on why you are asking this and what language you are most comfortable with. In general I wouldn't write such a macro (tool) in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://seleniumhq.org/ . You can easily write a script to do this with the inbuilt firefox plugin - very little coding required.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use curl.
You can easily setup a curl script to logon to web sites, download pages etc.